# Why are unused variables bad?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, warnings, llvm

I would like to know why an unused variable is bad.

Is it because the compiler would create a bigger binary? If yes, is there a tool/script which can add an `unused` keyword or something like that?

Comment: because if you don't use it, there is no point having it

Comment: @Ibu I ask this question because I use some api wich do not use a lot of variable, and I was impressed of the number there are

Comment: Why are they good? What are they doing there?

Comment: Are you discussing unused parameters, or unused variables?  Unused variables are a waste of space in the source; a decent compiler won't create them in the object file.  Unused parameters when the functions have to meet an externally imposed interface are a different problem; they can't be avoided as easily because to remove them would be to change the interface.  C++ allows you to declare the type but omit a name to indicate that it will be unused; it would be good if C were able to do that (but there are reasons related to historic C code that mean it cannot do so easily).

Comment: All you bumbles. Here is an example of an unused global variable. It is defined in a static member function, which isn't used. Done. Why have the code? Maybe some other version uses the function (DEBUG version maybe?).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The compiler gives you warnings to *hint* on things that could *potentially* be a problem or unintentional.

Unused variables will be optimized away most likely. But maybe you intended to do something with them – and in that case the compiler helpfully notes that you *may* have done something you didn't want.

What's the use in a variable you declare but neither read from nor write to?

Comment: Ok, I thought a large number of unused variable may influence the compilation.

Comment: It might take a bit more memory during compiling due to more entries needed in the symbol table, but apart from that, I guess you won't notice anything.

Comment: +1 this is definitely the best answer. For instance, many times I've added an extra index variable `j` or `k` but accidentally reused the previous one, and the compiler warning (which usually stops build due to `-Werror`) catches the bug before I even try running the program.

Answer (score 12):

Because...

> *Perfection is reached not when there’s nothing left to add, but when there’s nothing left to remove.*

Comment: `#include <stdio.h> int main() { printf("All tests passed\n"); }`. Ship it ;-p

Comment: @Steve: s/printf/puts/ ..  4 characters ('\n' not needed) closer to perfection...

Comment: @William: true, although generally I don't use `puts`, because generally some of my output needs formatting and I'd rather consistently use one function for all output. You're quite right that in this case that doesn't apply, so the only argument against `puts` is that sometimes explicit (linebreak) is better than implicit. For that matter, you could remove the whitespace too, although I'm pretty sure that wouldn't improve things ;-)

Answer (score 10):

In my humble opinion, unused variables complicate readability of your code. No matter what language you are using.

Comment: By checking sources right now, lots of them, this is the only warning I get but about 4000 times at different parts. I don't understand why one declares so many unused variables.

Answer (score 0):

at somepoint memory is limited. Memory stack get full and overloaded when there are unused variables in the code. Compiler will take more time to run the code. So as for the sake of memory consumption and memory optimisation unused variables are bad.